# When did Big Ears lose his fingers?

Tags: goblins-comic

I recently did a binge reading of webcomic, Goblins, and noticed that Big Ears the Goblin Paladin regained fingers when [his ears were healed](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/page-2-2021).

[image: Big Ears being healed, showing fingers being regrown]

When did he lose his fingers?  I don't remember seeing that.

Comment: You cannot name a more iconic pairing than *Goblins* and constant character redesigns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He lost the fingers when shielding the others from the LOL pearl [here](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/01172017-2).

[image: He has his left hand's fingers]

You can see when he wakes up, that [his left hand is partially obliterated](https://www.goblinscomic.com/comic/02132017-2).

[image: Ears, waking up, left hand largely gone]